# What happens to light as it enters a denser medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, refraction, boundary-conditions

I am a first year undergrad student doing optometry (never done any physics before in my life :( ). I got a question asking what happens when light enters a denser medium. I was told that the frequency of light doesn't change, but the wavelength decreases. Is that true? And if so, why does the frequency never change? As little maths as possible would be great - this subject is mostly very qualitative and I'm not a maths expert.

Comment: The phenomenon is called refraction, take your time and read the article here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction and introductory book on optics such as Optics by Eugene Hecht https://www.amazon.com/Optics-4th-Eugene-Hecht/dp/0805385665 is well worth checking out of your library

Comment: In my opinion the speed of light never slows down. Photons that get past the boundary will enter the denser medium and undulate between the atoms. Never losing speed and exiting the other side at the speed of light. The undulating causes the photon to have a longer path which is perceived as slowing down.

Comment: @boyfarrell Refraction (the bending of the ray at the interface) is _caused_ by light slowing down, but does not cause it. The slowing down of light has its own causes which are complicated and might be what the OP wants to know.

Answer (score 3):

Frequency depends upon source. It is just the number of peaks or troughs passing though a point each second.

Imagine you are holding one end of a rope and other end is tied to a wall and you are oscillating your hand up and down.Now the number of peaks passing on the rope through a point per second just depends on how you oscillate your hand. **Unless you change the frequency of oscillation of your hand,the frequency of wave on rope won't change.**

This is similar to the case of electromagnetic waves as well.Their frequency won't change in different mediums unless the source is changed.

Meanwhile wavelength decreases in a denser medium(its refractive index is high) as it travels slowly in it.

Comment: You could modify the rope to finish the analogy, perhaps a denser segment of it can mimick an optically denser medium here.

Comment: An anchor at the bottom of a pool attached to the rope that you are holding above the water line would be an excellent example.

Answer (score 2):

"I was told that the frequency of light doesn't change [...] Is that true? And if so, why does the frequency never change?

It is true. Frequency is the number of cycles of oscillations per second. Each cycle of oscillation is passed through the medium and from medium A into medium B and so on. You can't lose or gain cycles of oscillation on the way. If you *could* lose cycles, ask yourself: which ones? Every other cycle, every fifth cycle? Random cycles? It really doesn't make sense! Nor could you gain cycles.

Wavelength does decrease when light passes into a medium in which it travels more slowly. In the time for one oscillation the wavefronts don't travel as far.

Comment: Frequency is just as countable as wavelength.  How many E-field peaks pass a location each second?

Comment: I'm arguing that frequency *is* countable!

Comment: Apologies.  I touch of dyslexia.  But you can count the number of peaks in a length of one meter.

Comment: "But you can count the number of peaks in a length of one meter." You are right here, of course.

Comment: When you have only one photon the question “how many E-field peaks pass a location each second?” makes no sense but the photon still has a frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Light gets absorbed and re- emitted more in the denser medium and therefore  takes longer to pass through it

Comment: This use of absorption re-emission leads to non ending semantic misunderstanding when discussing the real electronic absorption phenomenon. A generic term like interaction should be preferable in my opinion. But this is a general comment.